# grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure when starting the peer node for fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I tried to build the development environment of fabric using the guide at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md

After `vagrant ssh` into the VM, I wanted to start a peer node to test the example chaincode to verify if I have set the environment correctly, so with the guide at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md

I `make peer`, and started the peer node by `peer node start --peer-chaincodedev`, but error appeared:

```
[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 008 [validator.vp] Failed requesting read certificate [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure].

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 009 [validator.vp] Failed requesting ECA certificate [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure].

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00a [validator.vp] Failed getting ECA certificate [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure].

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00b [validator.vp] Failed retrieving ECA certs chain [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure].

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00c [validator.vp] Failed registering node crypto engine [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure].

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00d [validator.vp] Failed registering peer [vp]: [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure]

[crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00e [validator.vp] Failed registering [vp]: [rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure]

grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp [::1]:7054: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {"localhost:7054" <nil>}

Failed to dial localhost:7054: grpc: the connection is closing; please retry.
```

I've also tried the optional step of security setup, `make membersrvc` and run it, but when running membersrvc, there is no output and no stop but just staying at there for several hours.

I have no idea why this appears and there seems no one else meeting the same problem with me after two-day searching. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Membership service do not generate any output. It just has to be started. Try to run your peer after membership service.

Comment: Could you please show the content of your `VagrantFile` ? or make sure that this line is exist, `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7054, host: 7054 # Membership service`

Comment: @SufiyanGhori This line sure exists...TAT

Comment: Running membersrvc didn't have any output and it even cannot stop until I pressed ctrl+C. So...it seems like there's something wrong with my `membersrvc` file...@SergeyBalashevich

Comment: @SergeyBalashevich I've also tried to remake `membersrvc` but the problem still exist, the procedure for membersrvc cannot stop

Comment: Just to be sure if we are on the same page. Could you please try to open first terminal window and run membersrvc process (the will be no output from it, do not press ctrl+c, just keep this process running), then open another terminal and try to start peer service.

Comment: @SergeyBalashevich Ah it works! Thank you so much ~mua